if $f_n \uparrow f$ prove $\mu(f_n\geq t)\rightarrow \mu(f\geq t)$
I think I  have  to use montone convergence theorem and I have followed this line

the sets $f_n\geq t$ are increasing
$\lim\mu(f_n\geq t)=\mu(\cup(f_n\geq t)=?\mu(f\geq t)$

if $x\in \cup(f_n\geq t) \rightarrow \exists \bar{n} : f_\bar{n}\geq t $ but $f \geq f_\bar{n}$
if $x\in f \geq t \rightarrow x \in f \geq t-\epsilon \forall \epsilon>0 $ but $ \exists n  : f\geq f_n \geq t- \epsilon \forall \epsilon>0 $
so $f_n \geq t$ so $x\in \cup f_n \geq t$
UPDATE
the result is not true as pointed out but this is my second approach

$\mu(f > t) \geq u (f_k>t) \forall k$  so passing it to limits I have
$\mu (f>t) \geq \lim \mu( f_k>t)$ so  $\mu (f>t) \geq \mu( \cup f_k>t)$

$\mu(f>t)=\mu(\lim f_k>t)=\mu (limsup f_k>t)=\mu (\cap \cap \cup (f_k > t+\frac{1}{m})) \leq \mu( \cup f_k > t+\frac{1}{m}) \leq \mu( \cup f_k > t)$



Thi is false. Counter-example: $f_n=1-\frac 1 n, f=1, t=1$.

@geetha290krm thanks . but where is the point that is not correct in my proof ? it is true with only >?

$n$ depends on $\epsilon$ so you won't get $f \ge t$ in the last line.

@geetha290krm ok thanks! sorry to bother you again there is a way to modify the proof if I  have only  >? I have read that the theorem is true in that way

@Dsrksidemath For $>$, you'll have that $\mathbf{1}{f{n}>t}$ is an increasing sequence (not strictly increasing but only increasing) which converges to $\mathbf{1}_{f>t}$ almost everywhere. You can conclude by Monotone Convergence Theorem.

@Mr.GandalfSauron and with $\geq$ ? is not converging almost everwhere to  $1_f\geq t$ ?

Take geeta290krm's example and see if you get convergence for $t=1$ or not. @Dsrksidemath

@Mr.GandalfSauron sorry but I don't understand the fact of icreasing sequence I mean I don't know how to prove . I have made a second approach could you tell me if it is correct please ? Thanks again

@Dsrksidemath I have posted an answer explaining it and other things. And secondly, you don't need to complicate so much. Just fix an $x\in X$ and look at what is happening to the sequence. Aristodog's answer provides the sufficient details and what you did is an immediate consequence of the continuity of measures from below and you can do without needing to be too explicit.

@Dsrksidemath Also, it is basic courtesy in this site to upvote and accept answers which you find useful. It is the only way you reward the user who has taken time to answer your query. You have not done so in many of your posts. The only upvote in Aristodog's short and compact answer is from me.

@Mr.GandalfSauron you are totally right and I am sorry for my behaviour . Your answer is very full of detail and I didn't upvote nothing because I still didn't understand . when you say " what you did is an immediate consequence of the continuity of measures from below and you can do without needing to be too explicit" I didn't find it immediate and I wanted to know if it was true or not  I needed to exlicit all passages because it was not clear to me and I am sorry if I offended you  it was not my intention

@Mr.GandalfSauron what I wrote with limsup etc... is correct ?  Please for me it is  important because  I am not a professor , I am self studing this and I tried my best to proceed. If I knew how to solve this problem on my own I wouldn't have bothered anyone let me know

@Dsrksidemath You directly have that $\mu(\lim\sup f_{k}>t)=\mu(\cap_{m\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq m} {f_{k}>t})$ as by monotonicty, if $f_{k}(x)>t$ for some $k$, then $f(x)>t$. And now the RHS is less than $\mu(\cup_{k\geq m}{f_{k}>t})\leq \mu(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}{f_{k}>t})$ . And now, by continuity of measure, $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}{f_{k}>t})=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu({f_{k}>t})$. That's it. Also, it was not about offence caused to anyone. It is about showing some basic courtesy to the users. Lately, there are less and less upvotes and more downvotes in posts.

@Dsrksidemath Lately, more questions receive downvotes and less and less posts gets upvoted and even less answes especially when it comes to graduate level topics. This only serves to make the site less accessible and less attractive to users. Like you said, you did not upvote because you did not understand it yet. That's totally fine. But there are other questions which were asked by you months ago and the answers still don't have upvotes and neither are they accepted. You can see how that might cause a potential long time user to just not participate in this site anymore.

@Mr.GandalfSauron Yes you are totally right I understand the problem . Thanks for all the time you spent with me you were super kind and I hope to see you next time

What you are trying to show is that $\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}\geq t}\to \int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{f\geq t}$.
Probabilistically speaking, this ammounts to showing that for an increasing sequence $X_{n}$ of random variables  converging to $X$ almost surely, you have $P(X_{n}\geq t)=P(X\geq t)$.
This is simply not true. Take $X_{n}=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $X=0$ .
Then you have $P(X_{n}\geq 0)=0$ but $P(X\geq 0)=1$.
The main problem is that $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}\geq t}$ does not converge almsot surely to $\mathbf{1}_{f\geq t}$ for all $t$. As you can see in the example above, the problem occurs when $t=0$.
However, if you take $>$ instead of $\geq$ . Then consider $x\in X$ such that $f_{n}(x)\to f(x)$ and some fixed $t\in\Bbb{R}$
Firstly, you have that $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}$ is increasing. To prove this take an $x$ and suppose $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}(x)=1$, then $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n+1}>t}(x)=1$ . And if $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}(x)=0$, then regardless you always have $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n+1}>t}(x)\geq\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}(x)=0$
Now,
If $f_{n}(x)>t$ for all large $n$, then $ f(x)\geq f_{n}(x)>t$ and hence $1=\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}(x)\to\mathbf{1}_{f>t}(x)=1$.
If $f_{n}(x)\leq t$ for infinitely many $n$, then monotonicity forces that $f_{n}(x)\leq t$ for all large $n$ and $f(x)\leq t$ and hence again $0=\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}(x)\to\mathbf{1}_{f>t}(x)=0$ .
Thus $\mathbf{1}_{f_{n}>t}\uparrow\mathbf{1}_{f>t}$ almost everywhere. Now apply Monotone Convergence Theorem to conclude.
Essentially this is the same as what @Aristodog did (+1) but restated in terms of indicators and increasing sequences.

$\mu(f_n >t) \le \mu(f > t)$
and
$\mu(f > t) \le \mu(\cup_k \{f_k > t\}) = \lim_k \mu(f_k >t)$

Can  you please look at my second apprach ? I think it's the same as yours but with a little more details . Thanks
